# Create single web app (WAR) from multiple web applications

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant

We already having an spring web application (maven project) say webApp1 which is hosted on production and working fine but now due some business requirements we want to develop an another web application say webApp2.

So some clients demands both apps, or some either one of them. we need freedom of which module to be deployed, there can be the case where some clients don't want webApp1 so deployment package must include only webApp2 or sometimes both.

**Approach 1:**

Lets create another maven project and develop individually, at the time of creating deployment package use of `Apache Ant` can be done which will create `WAR` file by combining libs,views,controllers of both the applications or of one. combining web.xml,root-context.xml,servlet-context.xml may be the manual task.

**Approach 2:**

After searching on approach 1 I come to know about `EAR` (similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936464/1629242).

`EAR` package (similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936464/1629242) can be the approach, but for this **do I need to convert existing application as EAR? or what changes are required in existing working web application webApp1?** also how I can control which module need to be added in `EAR`

Comment: Why can't you deploy them as separate packages (to the same application server if that's desired)?

Comment: @zapl if I choose to deploy two separate apps then integration of webApp1 and webApp2 can not be done. Consider a case where client demands functionality of webApp1 through webApp2 without login-logout flow or for this systems like CAS need to implemented.

Answer (score 1):

**As for approach 2**. it really depends how exactly do you host your application, what is the container. If it's Tomcat/Jetty which can be a pretty common choice, than EAR is not even an option, since they don't "understand" (can't process) EAR files.

**Regarding approach 1**. The 'manual' part of combining various xmls can be tedious and certainly error prone. Moreover, if you combine the xmls you won't get a real separation (at the level of classloader) between webapp1 and webapp2. After all totally different applications will be hosted in the same WAR.

So, IMHO, you should go for **approach 3**:

Keep webapp1 and webapp2 as different deployment units (different WARs). Keep different web.xml, spring configuration files and so forth.

Deploy these wars as 2 different files in the same container. Container will happily serve 2 different Wars. This way, spring beans, servlets, filters and so forth won't interfere between two apps at runtime. Moreover this approach can be fully automated.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer and approach, but in that way if we deploy both the apps then context must be different (correct me if I am wrong), so if in feature if client demands access to any other functionality from webApp1 through webApp2 (without login-logout flow) then it will hard or systems like CAS need to be implemented, correct?

Comment: Actually I am looking for solution which has single context in deployment but can be developed separately by separate team without worrying about existing webApp1

Comment: Even I am not looking for real separation at the level of classloader between webApp1 and webApp2. Beans created by webApp1 can be (need to be) access by webApp2 and vice versa.

Comment: it really depends on what is the level of separation you're looking for. As for me, if you're talking about different featured to be enabled or disabled for the same application, then its just a matter of configurations (http://www.togglz.org/) or alternatively you can solve it at the spring level (profiles, @Conditional annotation if you're on spring 4+). So I think you should specify exactly the requirements from this point of view. Will these apps have the same authentication policy? will they "talk to each other" (and what happens if, a tries to talk to b and b is not available at all)

Comment: I think its not just matter of enabling/disabling features of same application. Let me clear by real scenario. Our webApp1 is actually a examination framework and some clients demanding for some kind of learning framework too. So candidate will learn in webApp2 and at the end of course he/she will attempt for exam in webApp1. Clients/BA are imagining this as candidate will login to learning framework and if course is completed then he/she will appear for exam from that portal only (without logout from app2 to and login to app1) so yes, both app will talk to each other...

Comment: As this the case for some clients demands only for examination framework so for them our examination framework need to work individually where only exams need to be taken.

Comment: to me it sounds like two different modules in the same application :) BTW, Single Sign On doesn't really mean that application talk to each other. Its more like whether appB calls beans/stores data/calls web methods of app A and vise versa